# Encryption & Decryption in C#

Tags: c#, encryption

Here is my code blocks, 
I assume Decrypt method is not functioning, it returns some garbage value. I am new to this.

```
public string Encrypt(string toEncrypt, string key, bool useHashing)
{
    byte[] keyArray;
    byte[] toEncryptArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncrypt);

    if (useHashing)
    {
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
    }
    else
        keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);

    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    tdes.Key = keyArray;
    tdes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
    ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
    byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);

    return Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
}

public string Decrypt(string toDecrypt, string key, bool useHashing)
{
    byte[] keyArray;
    byte[] toEncryptArray = Convert.FromBase64String(toDecrypt);

    if (useHashing)
    {
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
    }
    else
        keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);

    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    tdes.Key = keyArray;
    tdes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

    ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateDecryptor();
    byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);

    return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray);
}



        String key = "ShHhd8a08JhJiho98ayslcjh";
    string tmp = "My Name Is Tanmoy Mitra";
    string encryptStr = Encrypt(tmp,key,false);
    Debug.Log("Encrypt Text:"+encryptStr);
    Debug.Log("Decrypt Text:"+Decrypt(encryptStr,key,false));
```

But it returns `��2�cU:EIs Tanmoy Mitra`
It works with //CipherMode.ECB mode, but I want to know why this CBC mode is not working in this case.Please help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

You're not specifying an IV (initialization vector). The encryption and decryption need to use the same IV. For example, one *bad* way of doing it would be:

```
tdes.IV = new byte[tdes.BlockSize / 8];
```

... in both encryption and decryption. Better would be to generate a random IV once when encrypting (it's done automatically when you create the crypto service provider) and remember it for when you decrypt.

From the [IV property documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.iv%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> The classes that derive from the SymmetricAlgorithm class use a chaining mode called cipher block chaining (CBC), which requires a key and an initialization vector to perform cryptographic transformations on data. **To decrypt data that was encrypted using one of the SymmetricAlgorithm classes, you must set the Key property and IV property to the same values that were used for encryption.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
[Serializable]
public class CriptoEngine
{

    #region Variables

    private string key;
    byte[] keyArray;
    byte[] arrayDecypt;
    byte[] resultArray;
    byte[] arrayEncrypt;

    #endregion

    #region Metodos Publicos

    public CriptoEngine(string user)
    {
        key = user;
    }
    public TDecrypData SetEncriptar<TEncr, TDecrypData>(TEncr objEncrypt)
    {
        object tEncr;
        arrayEncrypt = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(objEncrypt));
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
        hashmd5.Clear();
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        tdes.Key = keyArray; tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
        resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(arrayEncrypt, 0, arrayEncrypt.Length);
        tdes.Clear();
        Type t = typeof(TDecrypData);
        switch (t.Name)
        {
            case "Byte[]":
                tEncr = resultArray;
                break;
            default:
                tEncr = Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
                break;
        }            
        return (TDecrypData)tEncr;

    }

    public TEncryptData GetDescr<TDesc, TEncryptData>(TDesc objDecry)
    {
        arrayDecypt = Convert.FromBase64String(objDecry.ToString());
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
        hashmd5.Clear();
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        tdes.Key = keyArray;
        tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateDecryptor();
        resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(arrayDecypt, 0, arrayDecypt.Length);
        tdes.Clear();
        object crypto = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray);
        return (TEncryptData)crypto;
    }

    #endregion
}
```